# Multiple attachments for dojo's Uploader in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, dojo

I am building a form in which users can choose to upload multiple files using Dojo 1.8. I have the following code snippit that, when placed in a form, allows multiple file uploads for Chrome and Firefox:

```
var u = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    label: "Browse",
    multiple: true, 
    uploadOnSelect: false, 
    url: 'upload'
});
```

However, it is well-documented that IE9 does not support this feature of dojox.form.Uploader. Is there a workaround that would allow Internet Explorer users to upload multiple files?

Comment: Are you talking about allowing multiple files to be selected for upload at once, or simply allowing users to submit more than one file during any particular session?  I assume the former, but just want to be sure.

Comment: The former - users should be able to press Ctrl or Shift and click to select multiple files to upload at once. As far as I know, IE doesn't play nicely with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 and earlier do not support the `multiple` attribute on file input elements.  So, there is no way to select multiple files in one pass without resorting to Flash or Java.